# Como puedo implementar un configuración personalizada del toollbar de CKeditor?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, livewire

Los estoy haciendo con Livewire y alpine. De la siguienete forma y pues me funciona pero no se como configuarle el toolbar.
Este es mi codigo del textarea.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols mb-4">
            <div wire:ignore>
                <x-jet-label value="Resultados" />
                <textarea class="form-control" wire:model="service.resultados" x-data x-init="
                           ClassicEditor
                            .create( $refs.editorResultados)
                            .then(function(editor){
                                
                                editor.model.document.on('change:data', () => {
                                    @this.set('service.resultados', editor.getData())
                                   
                                })
                                
                            })
                            .catch( error => {
                                console.error( error );
                            } );" x-ref="editorResultados">
                </textarea>
                <x-jet-input-error for="service.resultados" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Este es el codigo que sugiere ckeditor para configurar el toolbar, y bueno lo que quiero es agregarle algunas otras funcionalidades.

```
toolbar: {
items: [
    'heading', '|',
    'fontfamily', 'fontsize', '|',
    'alignment', '|',
    'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', '|',
    'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'underline', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
    'link', '|',
    'outdent', 'indent', '|',
    'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList', '|',
    'code', 'codeBlock', '|',
    'insertTable', '|',
    'uploadImage', 'blockQuote', '|',
    'undo', 'redo'
],
shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true}
```

De antemano agradezco mucho si alguien me puede ayudar. Necesito quitar algunas y agregar otras que no están en el editor clásico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo queres es quitar esas opciones?, simplemente eliminalas del array;

```
toolbar: {
items: [
    'heading', '|',
    'fontfamily', 'fontsize', '|',
    'alignment', '|',
    'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', '|',
    'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'underline', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
    'link', '|',
    'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList', '|',
    'code', 'codeBlock', '|',
    'insertTable', '|',
    'undo', 'redo'
],
shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true}
```

Es decir, quitales las opciones uploadImage, outdent e indent.

Pero lo mejor que podes hacer es leer la documentacion oficial, alli esta todo

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/toolbar/toolbar.html